# Autoscaling in Sagemaker by Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, endpoint, autoscaling

all our AWS infra managed by Terraform, including the Sagemaker resources. We want to implement Autoscaling in our SM resources. We can't find Terraform solution to build our infra as a code.

In generally, ASG should be located in `aws_sagemaker_endpoint_configuration` >> `production_variants` blocks

references:

1. AWS documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-is-now-available-for-amazon-sagemaker/
2. TF documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_endpoint_configuration

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: You need to do it using regular autoscaling configs, nothing sage-maker specific in terms of the used resources, look at e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/APIReference/API_RegisterScalableTarget.html#API_RegisterScalableTarget_RequestParameters and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_target

Comment: thanks you, I thing this what I need

Answer (score 4):

so, from my researches it should be something as:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "sagemaker_target" {
  max_capacity       = var.max_instance_count
  min_capacity       = var.min_instance_count
  resource_id        = "endpoint/${aws_sagemaker_endpoint.endpoint.name}/variant/${var.service_name}-${var.site}-${var.environment}"
  role_arn           = aws_iam_role.sm_execution.arn
  scalable_dimension = "sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount"
  service_namespace  = "sagemaker"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "sagemaker_policy" {
  name               = "${var.service_name}-${var.site}-${var.environment}-target-tracking"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.sagemaker_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.sagemaker_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.sagemaker_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "SageMakerVariantInvocationsPerInstance"
    }
    target_value       = var.target_invocations
    scale_in_cooldown  = var.target_scale_in_cooldown
    scale_out_cooldown = var.target_scale_out_cooldown
  }
}
```

Comment: I will test it soon, but this a right direction

Comment: so? is that the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Taken a reference from the other answer, below is what my code looks like. Pasting here for some one's reference.

*Note* : I had to remove `role_arn` key from `aws_appautoscaling_target` resource so that it uses default service IAM role & also had to use `SageMakerEndpointInvocationScalingPolicy` string for policy `name` in `aws_appautoscaling_policy` resource to get same behavior as we get when we create auto scalling policy for sagemaker endpoint from aws console.

PS : Without above adjustments, TargetValue was not getting rendered wehn viewing from aws console & I was not manually able to change target value of terraform created auto scalling policy of sagemaker endpoint (as while updating TargetValue from console , was getting `Validation Exception like Only one Target Tracking Scaling policy for a given metric specification is allowed`. error etc

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "register_myendpoint_target" {
  max_capacity       = 2
  min_capacity       = 1
  resource_id        = "endpoint/${aws_sagemaker_endpoint.my_model-endpoint.name}/variant/${variant_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount"
  service_namespace  = "sagemaker"
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "autoscale_policy_my_endpoint" {
  name               = "SageMakerEndpointInvocationScalingPolicy" # Had to use this name ditto so that on console it doesn't show some custom policy is configured etc etc
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.register_myendpoint_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.register_myendpoint_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.register_myendpoint_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    target_value       = 100.0
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "SageMakerVariantInvocationsPerInstance"
    }
    scale_in_cooldown  = 300
    scale_out_cooldown = 300
  }
}
```