# how to add autoscaling policy to an sagemaker endpoint via terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sagemaker

based on sagemaker example, added an autoscaling policy ( sample code below) to an existing asynchronous sagemaker endpoint. however , looking into terraform documentation , to see if i can add autopolicy via terraform.Terraform documentation has all the resources need to create the asynchornous endpoint but not sure if it is possible to add auto scaling policy as well. there is one similar question but with untried solution in SO.

```
client = boto3.client(    "application-autoscaling") 
resource_id = ( "endpoint/" + endpoint_name + "/variant/" + "variant1")  
response = client.register_scalable_target(
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker",
    ResourceId=resource_id,
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",
    MinCapacity=0,
    MaxCapacity=5,
)
response = client.put_scaling_policy(
    PolicyName="Invocations-ScalingPolicy",
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker", 
    ResourceId=resource_id,  # Endpoint name
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",  
    PolicyType="TargetTrackingScaling",  # 'StepScaling'|'TargetTrackingScaling'
    TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
        "TargetValue": 5.0,  
         SageMakerVariantInvocationsPerInstance
        "CustomizedMetricSpecification": {
            "MetricName": "ApproximateBacklogSizePerInstance",
            "Namespace": "AWS/SageMaker",
            "Dimensions": [{"Name": "EndpointName", "Value": endpoint_name}],
            "Statistic": "Average",
        },
        "ScaleInCooldown": 600,
   ....
    },
)
```

Comment: " there is one " - where? You haven't provided any link.

Comment: @marcin - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598083/autoscaling-in-sagemaker-by-terraform

Comment: If terraform has the resource to create the ASG, you should be able to. Please try the solution in the link above.